# Issue with TableView Cell Edit Control in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios8

I am in the process of updating my application from iOS 7 to iOS 8. I am experiencing an issue with Table view edit control (UITableViewCellEditControl class).

When putting table in edit mode the table view edit control button (round selection icon, blue in color on selection) works as expected for both iOS 7 and iOS 8 when (BOOL)tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath: delegate method returns YES.

But, output is different when above mentioned delegate method returns NO.

For iOS 7 the edit control button is not visible as expected (see below image) .

[image]

For iOS 8 the edit control button is visible (see below image). Is this a bug or expected behaviour in iOS 8?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug.

Comment: What cell are you using ?. Custom cell ?

Comment: i can't reproduce this. how do you set up the cell?

Comment: @OnikIV - Issue is for all cell styles.

Comment: @bluedome - (BOOL)tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath: delegate method should return NO to replicate the issue.

Comment: Ok, I understand you are using UITableViewCell without subclassing. I think your problem is your tableView enter in edit mode, but there is a problem what make your cells don't enter in edit mode, and they don't redraw them contentView. If you put here your code, it will be easy to help you.

Comment: @OnikIV Result is same either I am using UITableViewCell or MyCustomTableViewCell. I am able to put tableView in edit mode. Everything is working fine apart from the issue I have mentioned above in my question.

<pre>

Comment: If you using you own customCell. In your case MyCustomTableViewCell, you can override setEditing:animated: methods, and test if this method is call or not. ( I think, this is probably mistake). If you put her your MyCustomTableViewCell.h, and your viewController data source and delegate methods, it's easy to help you.

Comment: @OnikIV Thanks a lot.
But, as I have mentioned there is no issue with tableView Or cell editing. Please see my code for reference https://gist.github.com/Satish/c3c79f882f7507e811ba

Comment: thanks. i confirmed. it seems to be a bug. if `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` returns NO, resolve this. but you can't do that, right?

Comment: @bluedome can you help me with the solution if you were able to resolve this?

Comment: could you accept that delegate method `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` returns NO? if not, AFAIK, there are no workarounds. pls report this bug to apple.

Comment: @bluedome That is not an option for me. After returning NO from tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath: delegate rows won't be editable. 

I have reported same to apple a week back. But there is no response yet from there site.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've tried your code (I need to do several changes). But in order than the editing style appear property only one, this:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.isEditing) 
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
}
```

Change when isEditing the style is delete. 
You need perform actions.